# Tensorflow dependencies in android studio application

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have followed the instructions for using tensorflow from

https://medium.com/@elye.project/applying-tensorflow-in-android-in-4-steps-to-recognize-superhero-f224597eb055

but the application crashes when I launch it.

I tried modifying the app's build.gradle by adding the following line inside the dependencies section

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.7.0'
```

My application has a class that uses the tensorflow library. Without this line that class contains many errors. With this line my application crashes.

The build is successful but the application crashes as soon as it launches on my samsung galaxy 8.

What am I missing in order to be able to use tensorflow in my application successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my issue thanks to this link

https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d

Logcat was telling me there was an `unsatisfiedlinkerror`

As it turns out, since my galaxy S8 has a 64 bit processor, it looks for the native library .so files in a "arm64" folder that my android project does not have.

the solution is to add this to the defaultConfig section of the app's build.gradle:

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }
```